# Run same macro on different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 10 worksheets. I recorded a macro for creating a pivot tables from the first worksheet.

When I run the macro in another worksheet it just created the same pivot table containing data from the first worksheet even I had replaced the worksheet name with ActiveSheet in the script.

I double checked the script but I could not found why it always produce the same pivot table.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim TheRange As String
'
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
TheRange = "WorksheetConnection_ActiveSheet!$A$1:$D$" & lastrow
'
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TheRange"), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    ActiveSheet.Range("E1"), TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion15
Cells(1, 5).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields.GetMeasure _
    "[Range].[Store_CODE]", xlSum, "Sum of Store_CODE"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( 
_
    "PivotTable1").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of Store_CODE]"), _
    "Sum of Store_CODE"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields("[Range].[Date]")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[Measures].[Sum of Store_CODE]")
    .Caption = "Distinct Count of Store_CODE"
    .Function = xlDistinctCount
End With
End Sub


enter code here
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend storing reference to worksheet in a variable and use variable instead of `ActiveSheet`: `Dim ws As Worksheet  Set ws = Worksheets("ws_name")`, then replace `ActiveSheet` with `ws`.

Comment: If your source are worksheet data, a simple loop can do it. However, seeing your sample code, your source is external and I am not sure if each sheet have different `connection` source. We can iterate each connections but I don't know if we can check which sheet the connection was called.

Comment: The source data are from the worksheets. I generated the code through record macro. Not sure why sourceType was automatically set to external.